Any idea of the location of this painting?

Very old painting no idea where this is if anyone has ideas please share!!

Could you please provide a higher resolution photo of the artist's signature in the lower right corner?

What research have you done so far to try to identify the location?

Google Lens doesn't find any relevant results for either the (frame-cropped) picture, or a crop of just the signature.

IMO the photo hasn't enough resolution to at least decipher the signature reliably. Because of low resolution, no image search is possible either. Questioner doesn't react on comments. Thus, i vote to close the question.

Do you know anything about the artist?  If so, please add it to the question.  Also keep in mind that many landscape painters depicted imaginary landscapes, so it's entirely possible that this isn't anywhere.

You tagged the question “Italy”? What makes you think it’s there? Could this yield any more specific details?
